# Правильно ли называть TypeScript Compiler компилятором?

Tags: typescript, терминология, компилятор

Хочу разъяснить за свой вопрос:
Компилятор - программа, которая преобразует код в машинный/байт код
Но tsc же не делает этого, правильно ли его называть таковым?

Comment: Было бы странно не называть компилятором то, у чего в названии написано "Compiler" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для любого языка программирования можно построить виртуальную машину, в которой именно этот язык будет машинным кодом, и JavaScript тут не исключение.

Более того, [стандарт языка Ecmascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-intro) описывает именно такую ВМ!

---

Если взять *изначальное* определение компилятора - то байт-кода там не было, только машинный код. Но потом байт-код Java был реализован "в железе", и стал машинным кодом... на платформах, которые так толком никем и не использовались. Но этого формально было достаточно, чтобы считать `javac` компилятором. А дальше появился .NET со своим байт-кодом, который в железе никто не делал, но при этом и не считать `csc` компилятором тоже не получалось, ведь байт-код строился на очень похожих принципах.

С тех пор требование "железной" реализации машинного кода разрушено, и компилятором называют любую программу, которая преобразует код из высокоуровнено представления в относительно низкоуровневое.

Comment: "Относительно низкоуровневое" - как-то перебор про js :)

Comment: @Qwertiy javascript относительно typescript лежит уровнем ниже, потому и "относительно низкоуровневое"